# Command Line Arguments conflicting on Unity 3.5.7 Windows x64 Application

Tags: unity-game-engine, command-line-arguments

Im trying to test a build of an application using Unity 3.5.7 on a Windows x64 machine using dual monitors at 1920x1080 each. The app itself works, and when using -force-opengl command line to run the app it runs just fine but it will run in window mode. Same thing with the -popupwindow command, the app will run fine but filling both screens with DirectX.
Real problem is when i try to use both arguments on the same app at the same time. The app will run borderless and using OpenGl renderer, but the app wont fill the screens. Ive done this with DirectX but when i force my app into OpenGL it will not allow the app to run in all the space in both screens.

The machine is using an Nvidia 740 GFX card.
OpenGL ver. 4.5.

Is there any way to run the application on both screens simulating a full screen borderless window running OpenGL?

Comment: NB did you google "unity3d borderless window" for many discussions of this old chestnut

Comment: I actually looked for a way like 6 months ago to run my app on fullscreen on 2 screens, tried many answers but none of them worked but -popupwindow. Now I need to force OpenGL for a new project and im not finding any info about this problem.
Due to some limitations I need to use that version of Unity, no chance of changing that.

Comment: ah 4.5!  sorry, I did not notice.  sounds like you're building a physical simulator or the like.